# MySQL and MySQL safe won't start

Tags: server, mysql

I've problem with MySQL server on 18.04 LTS. I can run the MySQL server and no error on `/var/log/mysql/error.log`, When I run mysqld_safe it only shown this

```
2019-08-14T01:21:17.308139Z mysqld_safe Logging to syslog.
2019-08-14T01:21:17.313454Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
2019-08-14T01:21:17.341854Z mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
2019-08-14T01:21:17.588087Z mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

And nothing happen, I still can't run mysql service via systemctl start mysql. Is there anyway to fix it? Thanks

This's the output of the journalctl -xe

```
Aug 14 08:25:46 sgp.easycode.id mysqld[16814]: 2019-08-14T01:25:46.211036Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
Aug 14 08:25:46 sgp.easycode.id mysqld[16814]: Initialization of mysqld failed: 0
Aug 14 08:25:46 sgp.easycode.id systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 14 08:25:46 sgp.easycode.id mysqld[16814]: 2019-08-14T01:25:46.213464Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
Aug 14 08:25:46 sgp.easycode.id systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 14 08:25:46 sgp.easycode.id systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit mysql.service has failed.
--
-- The result is RESULT.
Aug 14 08:25:46 sgp.easycode.id systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 14 08:25:46 sgp.easycode.id systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
-- Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Automatic restarting of the unit mysql.service has been scheduled, as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Aug 14 08:25:46 sgp.easycode.id systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down.
Aug 14 08:25:46 sgp.easycode.id systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 14 08:25:46 sgp.easycode.id systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 14 08:25:46 sgp.easycode.id systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit mysql.service has failed.
--
-- The result is RESULT.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. First after long time searching, I see that /var/lib/mysql folder is set permission to root and not to mysql user, so I don chmod mysql:mysql on /var/lib/mysql. 2nd is the /var/log/mysql folder and file is set to root, I need to change it back to mysql:adm so I did it, and my mysql server run again without problem, seems I mess up with chown root:root .* on /root so cause everything change to root. I got lucky it still boot anyway.